# Fetch is not working in nextjs 13 version using graphql client library after fetching data for some time

Tags: javascript, next.js, graphql

**Applo client code in apploclient.js**

```
import { ApolloClient, HttpLink, InMemoryCache } from "@apollo/client";
import { registerApolloClient } from "@apollo/experimental-nextjs-app-support/rsc";

import {
  NextSSRInMemoryCache,
  NextSSRApolloClient,
} from "@apollo/experimental-nextjs-app-support/ssr";

export const { getClient } = registerApolloClient(() => {
  console.log(process.env.UMBRACO_DOMAIN_GRAPHQL)
  return new NextSSRApolloClient({
    link: new HttpLink({
      uri: 'https://localhost:44328/graphql/',
    }),
    cache: new NextSSRInMemoryCache(),
  });
});
```

**Code in root file**

```
import { gql } from "@apollo/client";
import { getClient } from "@/utilis/apolloClient";
const PrimartNavQuery = gql`
  query {
    contentByGuid(id: "6fa7ad54-7c4b-488a-9af7-00f046609b53") {
      name
      namedProperties {
        ... on DG_Navigation {
          mainNavigation {
            links {
              name
              target
              url
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
;
```

Fetching the code like below

```
  const PrimaryNavLinks = await getClient().query({ query: PrimartNavQuery });
  console.log(PrimaryNavLinks);
```

Below is the terminal Error

[image: Browser Error]

[image: Terminal error]

Fetch is not working